# Use the REST API from Parse.com to send specific Push Notifications

Tags: java, parse-platform

I have a server-program, written in java.

I would like to use the REST API from Parse.com to send Push-Notifications to specific users from my app.

This is the Code for a ParseQuery

```
ParseQuery query = ParseIntallation.query();
query.whereEqualTo("username", USERAME);
ParsePush.sendMessageInBackground("Push-Notification!", query);
```

Before I saved the username in the app to the ParseInstallation.

But now I am a little bit overstrained how to set up the whole CURL thing to send a ParseQuery from my java-server to Parse.com.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: it is not recommended to  send the notification from your app.
The better way is to create Cloud function

Comment: @Alon: I don't want to send notifications from my app. I want to send it from my java-server.

Comment: This is not recommended, cause in  this case you have to enable the notification from outside in the setting and than everyone can send request to the url and this will send notification.
You can do it, but it bad idea. you can  do code cloud on parse,

Comment: Can I connect my java-server with the Code Cloud? Because I have the Information on my java-server WHEN, WHICH Notifications should be send and WHO should receive it. I can't do this in Code Cloud directly. It is a tcp/ip-Messaging app. So my app sends something to my tcp/ip-java-server and the server sends the notification to the app. But I want to change it, so that parse sends the notifications, so that it doesn't come directly from my java-server.

Comment: yes, take a look on ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground , this helps you to call to the function on the cloud and pass information to this function